# LiveData returns wrong Object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, dagger-hilt

I added Hilt to my project and now `LiveData` returns wrong `Object type`. Maybe I made some wrong changes in my code.
`getAllCurrencies` returns `LiveData<Resource<Unit>>` but it should `LiveData<Resource<Currencies>>`

ViewModel:

```
class SplashScreenViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
private val roomDatabaseRepository: RoomDatabaseRepository,
private val retrofitRepository: RetrofitRepository) : ViewModel() {

fun getAllCurrencies(mainCurrency: String) = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
       emit(Resource.loading(data = null))
        try {
            emit(Resource.success(data = retrofitRepository.getAllCurrencies(mainCurrency)))
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            emit(Resource.error(data = null, message = exception.message ?: "Error Occurred!"))
        }
    }
```

Repository: (It returns good type)

```
class RetrofitRepository @Inject constructor(val currenciesApiHelper: CurrenciesApiHelper) {

suspend fun getAllCurrencies(mainCurrency: String) {
  currenciesApiHelper.getAllCurrencies(mainCurrency)
}
```

Comment: So how to change it to not `Unit`? The problem is with Hilt. If I delete `@Inject` from `Reposotory` It returns `Currencies`

Comment: Add `return currenciesApiHelper.getAllCurrencies(mainCurrency)` in your repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `return currenciesApiHelper.getAllCurrencies(mainCurrency)` in to Repository.

---

(optional) Following is the way I do it with MVVM:

I'll assume that you have Currency as a model declared somewhere already.

**Status**

```
sealed class Status<out T> {
    class Loading<out T> : Status<T>()
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Status<T>()
    data class Failure<out T>(val exception: Exception) : Status<T>()
}
```

**Fragment/Presentation Layer**

```
viewModel.fetchCurrencies(mainCurrency)
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
                when (result) {
                    is Status.Loading<*> -> {
                        //display a ProgressBar or so
                    }

                    is Status.Success<*> -> {
                        //Status.Success<*> can also be Status.Success<ArrayList<Currency>>
                        //hide the ProgressBar
                        val currencies = result.data as ArrayList<Currency> 
                    }

                    is Status.Failure<*> -> {
                        //log the exception
                    }
                }
            })
```

**ViewModel**

```
private val repo = Repository()

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun fetchCurrencies(mainCurrency: String): LiveData<Status<MutableList<Currency>>> =
        liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Status.Loading())

            try {
                repo.getCurrencies(mainCurrency).collect {
                    emit(it)
                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emit(Status.Failure(e))
                Log.e("ERROR:", e.message!!)
            }
        }
```

**Repository (single datasource)**

Using Firestore instead here as I'm not 100% certainly sure about your way.

Do what `retrofitRepository.getAllCurrencies(mainCurrency)` should do and then offer the result.

```
private val fs: FirebaseFirestore = Firebase.firestore

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun getCurrencies(mainCurrency: String): Flow<Status<MutableList<Currency>>> = callbackFlow {

        val subscription = fs.collection("currencies")
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ ->
                if (snapshot != null) {
                    val result = snapshot.toObjects(Currency::class.java)
                    offer(Success(result))
                }
            }

        awaitClose { subscription.remove() }
    }
```

Using coroutines is by the way quite sweet. Have a look here:

[Learn advanced coroutines with Kotlin Flow and LiveData](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-kotlin-coroutines/#0)

[Android Coroutines: How to manage async tasks in Kotlin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6manrgTPzyA)

Hope it helps :)